# Sourcemap support for firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get sourcemaps to work, when developing firebase functions in typescript.

In my `tsconfig.json` file a have source maps enabled.

This generated the sourcemaps. I then include this line in my `index.ts` file:

```
import 'source-map-support/register';
```

And then it seems to work. Is this correct configured, and `source-map-support` to the projects `package.json` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you need to do a few things, some of which is documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support):

1. `npm install source-map-support`
2. Enable `sourceMap` in `tsconfig.json` (**not** package.json!) by adding:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  },
```

3. Import the library into your file

   - If you're using ES6 modules: `import 'source-map-support/register'`
   - If you're using commonJS modules: `require('source-map-support').install();`

---

the result would transform this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_location' of null
    at /user_code/lib/http_actions.js:173:74
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (/user_code/lib/http_actions.js:4:58)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

into this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_location' of null
    at /user_code/src/http_actions.ts:183:33
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (/user_code/lib/http_actions.js:4:58)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: Does this still work? It seems like it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I can confirm that it does indeed still work exactly as specified!  As per [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors), as long as the `logger.error` call includes an `Error` object, we get the stack printout. And the filename and line number points correctly to the .ts source file.

Comment: I went into some detail on my implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63866829).