# How to add source map support for firebase functions written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a really difficult time getting source maps to work with firebase functions and TypeScript.

The official firebase tutorial for adding TypeScript doesn't really go into the details of how to set up your IDE so that you see the correct error messages. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript):

> During firebase deploy, your project's index.ts is transpiled to
> index.js, meaning that the Cloud Functions log will output line
> numbers from the index.js file and not the code you wrote. To make it
> easier for you to find the corresponding paths and line numbers in
> index.ts, firebase deploy creates functions/lib/index.js.map. You can
> use this source map in your preferred IDE or via a node module.

This is literally the only bit if information they give you.

I've also found this stack overflow question which explains how to do that: [Sourcemap support for firebase functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321965/sourcemap-support-for-firebase-functions)

But this doesn't seem to work anymore.

**What I've tried:**

In my index.ts file I import source-map-support like this:

```
import "source-map-support/register";
```

and my tsconfig file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

My error messages still look like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a third party provided the explanation of Setting up Firebase Cloud Functions to use TypeScript, you can refer to this [link](https://www.codementor.io/@muhammedali956/setting-up-firebase-cloud-functions-to-use-typescript-gfum40hwm) for details.

Comment: Those look like linter errors. Source mapping has to do with runtime errors. Try logging an error expressly in a function and see what sort of output comes up.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend excluding your functions/lib folder from linting, as TypeScript's compiled JavaScript often does its own thing, and doesn't need to be pretty.

Comment: @ShawnDiWu That tutorial is excellent. However, it skips the bit about mapping error messages. On that front, the doc says to ["put the following line at the top of the _compiled_ file,"](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support#programmatic-usage) that is, the require/import statement. Maybe that's what you should look into?