# How to show TypeScript source in Firebase Cloud Function callable stacktraces?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I have a set of Cloud Functions that perform CRUD-like functions to get an individual resource, list resources and so forth, `getWidgetByURL`, `listWidgets`, `deleteWidget`.

For a broader context, these are written in a single `src/service.ts` file and the `src/index.ts` exposes a set of callables:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as service from './service'

const region = 'europe-west1'

exports.addJob = functions.region(region).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    functions.logger.debug('addJob called with data', data)
    const job = await service.addJob(data.title, data.company,
      data.location, data.applyUrl, data.salary, data.tags)
    return job
  } catch (err) {
    functions.logger.error(err)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'internal server error', err)
  }
})
```

During the development cycle I run `npm run build` locally to compile to JavaScript into the target `lib` directory. Note the `*.map` files are produced.

[image]

In production, if a runtime error occurs, the stacktrace shown within Firebase console logs shows only the .js files callstack.

[image]

The debug process involves having to locate the runtime error in my local `lib/service.js` file and then by manually find the corresponding line in the corresponding source code `lib/service.ts` file. Tedious.

Is it possible for stacktraces to automatically make use of the .map files to produce something more useable? If not, what is the best practice/workflow?

Answer (score 7):

We use [node-source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) for this. I tried this just a few minutes ago and it worked just fine.

Assuming you're using NPM, run `npm install source-map-support`. (Not `--save-dev` of course, you'll need it at runtime).

In index.ts, import `source-map-support/register` early, preferrably first thing, like so:

```
// index.ts
import "source-map-support/register";
```

It doesn't much matter how this compiles. As far as I can tell, the call really just needs to happen in the main module there, and it compiles out early enough to make the magic happen.

Now, to test! As per [this Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors), as long as the `logger.error` call includes an `Error` object, we get the stack printout (handy for testing). Logging an error like so, then:

```
// foo.ts
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const { logger } = functions;

...

const error = new Error("This should log.");
logger.error(error);
```

This compiles from line *83* in foo.ts to line *54* in foo.js.

And once triggered we get this in the Firebase functions console:

[image]

As you can see, the filename and line number point correctly to line **83** the **.ts** source file!

Since this has to do with logging, I should note that because we use Firebase Cloud Functions on the Node.js 10 runtime, the old `console.log` syntax is kinda spoopy. So in our tsconfig.json file, we get to have `lib: ["es2018"], target: "es2018"`, but we also need to use `functions.logger.*` to get the same behavior as we got with `console.*`. As usual, throwing any old `Error` object will do as well.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee) handy for the Node.js 10 migration. I'll include it here in case that ends up being relevant for you with this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the module [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support).  Just install the module with npm, then put one line of code at the top of your index.js.

```
require('source-map-support').install();
```

Comment: That's the compiled index.js, right? For sure not index.ts? I'd like to have compilation and upload happen in one build step if it's possible, without having to manually build, add a line to the output, then deploy.